# How to Save the HashMap in Room database without using JSON & GSON?

Tags: android, android-room

I am trying to store Address in HashMap but the compiler gives the  error: 
Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it. private java.util.HashMap address;

```
 error: 
    Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it. private java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String> address;
```

I am using the MapTypeConverter but it doesn't work

```
object MapTypeConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun stringToMap(value: JsonElement): Map<String, String> {
        return Gson().fromJson(value,  object : TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.type)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun mapToString(value: Map<String, String>?): String {
        return if(value == null) "" else Gson().toJson(value)
    }
}
```

Room Entity

```
@Entity
data class User(
    var ownerName: String? = null,
    var shopNumber: String? = null,
    var deviceToken: String? = null,
    var altNumber: String? = null,
    var address: Map<String, String>? = null
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var uId: String = "NA"
}
```

App DataBase

```
@Database(
    entities = [User::class,ProductDetails::class,CategoryDetails::class],
    version = 1
)
@TypeConverters(ConverterListToString::class,MapTypeConverter::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase(){

    abstract fun getUserDao(): UserDao
    abstract fun getProductDao(): ProductDao
    abstract fun getCategoryDao(): CategoryDao

    companion object{

        @Volatile
        private var instance: AppDatabase? = null
        private val LOCK = Any()

        operator fun invoke(context: Context) = instance ?: synchronized(LOCK){
            instance ?: buildAppDataBase(context).also {
                instance = it
            }
        }

        private fun buildAppDataBase(context: Context) =
            Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                AppDatabase::class.java,
                 "TradersDatabase.db"
            ).build()
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code? Always add some implementation with the question.

Comment: I am just add my implementation

Comment: And whats the error you are getting?

Comment: I am getting this error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it. private java.util.Map address;

Comment: And can you show your  `Entity` class of `room`

Comment: I have added database class ,entity class and typeConverter

Comment: Can you check answer below, and accept it if it helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String` instead of `JsonElement`

```
object MapTypeConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun stringToMap(value: String): Map<String, String> {
        return Gson().fromJson(value,  object : TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.type)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun mapToString(value: Map<String, String>?): String {
        return if(value == null) "" else Gson().toJson(value)
    }
}
```

And your `Entity` should be like this

```
@Entity
data class User(
    var ownerName: String? = null,
    var shopNumber: String? = null,
    var deviceToken: String? = null,
    var altNumber: String? = null,

    @TypeConverters(MapTypeConverter::class)
    var address: Map<String, String>? = null
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var uId: String = "NA"
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but this is also not working and give the same error

Comment: error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it. private java.util.HashMap address;

Comment: Also add `@TypeConverters(MapTypeConverter::class)var address: Map<String, String>? = null` to your field

Answer (score 0):

You need to add converted to your `entity`

```
@Entity
data class User(
    var ownerName: String? = null,
    var shopNumber: String? = null,
    var deviceToken: String? = null,
    var altNumber: String? = null,
    @TypeConverters(MapTypeConverter::class)
    var address: Map<String, String>? = null
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var uId: String = "NA"
}
```

You need to change `JsonElement` to `String` in `stringToMap` function

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Okay, u didint add it in the question first.

Comment: there is an issue in your typeConverter conversion method.

Comment: Yes I think so.